# How do I escape an escape character with ANTLR 4?

Tags: escaping, antlr, quotes, antlr4

Many languages bound a string with some sort of quote, like this:

`"Rob Malda is smart."`

ANTLR 4 can match such a string with a lexer rule like this:

`QuotedString : '"' .*? '"';`

To use certain characters within the string, they must be escaped, perhaps like this:

`"Rob \"Commander Taco\" Malda is smart."`

ANTLR 4 can match this string as well;

`EscapedString : '"' ('\\"|.)*? '"';`

(taken from p96 of The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference)

Here's my problem:  Suppose that the character for escaping is the same character as the string delimiter.  For example:

`"Rob ""Commander Taco"" Malda is smart."`

(This is perfectly legal in Powershell.)

What lexer rule would match this?  I would think this would work:

`EscapedString : '"' ('""'|.)*? '"';`

But it doesn't.  The lexer tokenizes the escape character `"` as the end of string delimiter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Negate certain characters with the `~` operator:

```
EscapedString : '"' ( '""' | ~["] )* '"';
```

or, if there can't be line breaks in your string, do:

```
EscapedString : '"' ( '""' | ~["\r\n] )* '"';
```

You don't want to use the non-greedy operator, otherwise `""` would never be consumed and `"a""b"` would be tokenized as `"a"` and `"b"` instead of a single token.

Comment: It works, thank you.  But it only works if I use the greedy quantifier, not the non-greedy one.  Why is that?

Comment: @james.garriss you're welcome. I added some extra info on the non-greedy matching.

Comment: It's very interesting to see how the negation functions like a non-greedy quantifier.  Cool.

Answer (score 2):

(Don't vote for this answer; vote for @Bart Kiers' answer.)

I'm offering this for completeness, as it's a small piece of a Powershell grammar.  Combining the escape logic from p76 in The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference with Bart's answer, here are the rules necessary for lexing escaped strings in Powershell:

```
EscapedString
    : '"'      (Escape | '""'   | ~["])* '"'
    | '\''     (Escape | '\'\'' | ~['])* '\''
    | '\u201C' (Escape | .)*? ('\u201D' | '\u2033')   // smart quotes
    ;

fragment Escape
    : '\u0060\''    // backtick single-quote
    | '\u0060"'     // backtick double-quote
    ;
```

These rules handle the following four ways to escape strings in Powershell:

```
'Rob ''Commander Taco'' Malda is smart.'
"Rob ""Commander Taco"" Malda is smart."
'Rob `'Commander Taco`' Malda is smart.'
"Rob `"Commander Taco`" Malda is smart."
```